# Neccesary to fetch hash from database ? password_hash bcrypt

Tags: php, mysql, hash, bcrypt

I use PHP's password_hash and bcrypt algorithm to hash my passwords. They are in MySQL database.

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

As obvious every hash generated by this function is different. But is it really necessary, to identify user by email/login or something to grab his hash from database and then verify it with PHP's `password_verify()`?

Is it really necessary to make this query and then check?

I mean, is it possible to check hash before, and after only do query to check if it matches this one in MySQL?

Or something else maybe? I remember years ago I used something like checking inside query, like

```
WHERE login = $login and pass = PASSWORD($password)
```

Especially I mean this `PASSWORD($password)`?

Is there other option than fetch user's hash from Database and then verify this hash with `password_verify()`?

Comment: You'll have to dig into the database no matter what. I'm not sure how you're imagining *any* solution wouldn't involve a database call here. What would your "check hash before" be checking *against*?

Comment: @cee Well, in a "traditional" MD5 hash or such you can "check before" (asterisk, asterisk, footnote, warning…).

Comment: @deceze You can calculate the hash before querying with MD5, but you'd still have to do the query to see if the hash matches what you have on file.

Comment: No, select using other column match and then test password using `password_verify('plain text', $hashed_from_db);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's necessary. You need the unique salt generated during hashing, encoded as part of the hash, to do the comparison. That's also exactly why this algorithm is so strong for password storage.

Comment: Thank you a lot :).